# 'Invalid credentials' with Ionic View App

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to preview a ionic app using the 'ionic view app' on android but when I try to log in with my email and password an 'invalid credentials' message displays on top.
The problem is I have an ionic account with the same email and two apps linked and ready to test so I don't understand why can't logging in.

So, summarizing: my regular ionic account seems that it isn't working on ionic view android app.

Answer (score 1):

same issue on iOS, the app says "invalid credentials" on login.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the new app and not the legacy app.
Here are the links to the new app:

[Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ionicframework.view&hl=en)

[Apple](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ionic-view/id849930087?ls=1&mt=8)

More information [here](https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115012098448-Can-t-use-or-log-into-Ionic-View).